# error backing up to encrypted HFS+ backup disk using Time Machine on High Sierra

Tags: mac, backup, encryption, time-machine, macos-highsierra

I've recently upgraded my MacBook pro to High Sierra from Yosemite. I am trying to use a NEW external hard disk drive for Time Machine backups. I've formatted the drive to MACOS extended (journaled, encrypted), however when I mount the disk I am not asked for the password. When I try to set up Time machine backups with this drive by going to System Preferences > Time Machine > Select Disk > Use Disk, I get the following error:

"There was an error preparing the Time Machine backup disk XXX. This Core Storage logical volume is already decrypting."

I haven't been able to find much on the web about this error except a couple of websites stating that you shouldn't try to use encyption with Time Machine on High Sierra as your drive will be inadvertently converted to APFS. This has not happened in my case, Disk Utility shows that the format is MACOS extended, journaled, encypted.

Could anyone help me sort this out please?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried backing up to an encrypted HFS+ drive myself, so I'm not sure what would happen if I did, but from the message you are getting it sounds like TimeMachine doesn't want to use the encrypted drive, and is trying to decrypt it, which takes time. It is possible that the drive is currently decrypting and TimeMachine should start working once that is done. I answered another question about that [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232782/how-to-check-encryption-status-completeness-of-an-external-disk/236053).

So you don't have to click the link, this is what I said there:

> If you type the following command in Terminal you will get all sorts of info on all the corestorage volumes currently attached to your Mac, including the conversion status you are looking for:
>
> ```
> diskutil cs list
> ```
>
> There are more answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232782/how-to-check-encryption-status-completeness-of-an-external-disk/236053).
>
> One of my favorites is Nick Bedford's answer towards the bottom of that page that gives you just the status of each volume without all the other info.
>
> ```
> diskutil cs list | grep -e "Conversion" -e "Volume Name"
> ```

If my theory is correct, once you have run that command if you scroll down a bit you should see:

```
    Encryption Status:       Unlocked
    Conversion Status:       Converting (backward)
```

which means the drive is being decrypted. If TimeMachine is not working because of the encryption then it should work again once that process is complete. If you have nothing on the drive and want to 'speed up' that process then you can reformat the drive as a normal HFS+ journaled partition, without the encryption turned on and then trying Time Machine then.

I'm not sure the encryption is the problem, but the error message seems to indicate that it is, so I am curious to see what the status is on the encryption and conversion status of your core storage partition, and if waiting for the decryption to finish/reformatting fixes the problem. Good luck!

Comment: @Jess I just saw a link to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/184789/is-it-possible-to-backup-to-an-airport-disk-formatted-with-journaling/1288497) question off to the right and I'm wondering if you are facing a similar problem. What is your TimeMachine drive plugged in to? Directly in to the computer, or using an AirPort base station? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Running diskutil shows the drive (which is connected to the computer directly via USB) is being decrypted as you predicted. It doesn't seem to complete the process though. As the drive is empty I'm inclined to reformat. Can I use FileVault encryption or will I encounter the same problem? Also, I have another encrypted Time Machine backup drive which I haven't plugged in since upgrading to High Sierra. Will I encounter the same problem if I plug it in? May I even lose my backups? I'd be very grateful for your thoughts.

Comment: @Jess Corestorage encryption is FileVault encryption. FileVault is a name in the System Preferences to make it easier to enable/disable, but it is really just core storage encryption under the covers. So turning on FileVault will result in the same issue.

Comment: @Jess I'm not sure why that drive wanted to decrypt before backing up, and why it failed, but the worst that should happen when plugging in old encrypted drives is that they try to decrypt as well (which shouldn't happen). I doubt they'll spontaneously erupt or anything. If you are afraid that TimeMachine will force them to decrypt as well (it shouldn't, but just in case) then just make sure TM backups are disabled before plugging them in, and you will be able to read from them at will without anything happening. Even if they do decrypt you can still read the files off of them.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, you've been most helpful. After you initial response I tried to reformat the drive to MACOS extended (journaled) but the process failed repeatedly, so I returned the drive as defective and got a replacement which I've formatted to HFS+ without problems. I've also been able to set up Time Machine. The drive is unencrypted, though, is there any unproblematic way of encrypting it in High Sierra? Also, wrt my older Time Machine drive, ideally I'd like to continue using it for backups, is there any known issue with High Sierra and encrypted external Time Machine drives?

Comment: For example, this post from September 2017 https://bombich.com/blog/2017/09/29/think-twice-before-encrypting-your-hfs-volumes-on-high-sierra seems to suggest that one shouldn't try to encrypt external hard drives in High Sierra because they may be converted to APFS. Has the issue been fixed by any chance?