# Encrypted external drive accessible w/o password after backup/restore

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, encryption, superduper

I've got a 4TB LaCie Rugged drive that I want to use as my main encrypted backup drive for my Mac (Mojave).
Previously I was using a 2TB WD My Passport drive and I wanted to transfer all content (Time Machine backups and regular manual backups of images and various things) to the new drive.
The steps I took to do this were:

1. Formatted the LaCie drive to `Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)` and set an encryption password
2. Copied all files from the WD drive to the LaCie drive using SuperDuper v3.3.1, set to "Backup - All files" mode.

After 1., when plugging in the LaCie drive, it asked for a password to access it (which I stored in keychain for convenience).
However, after 2., when plugged in the LaCie drive to another Mac laptop, it allowed access without asking for an encryption password!

I initially thought that SuperDuper reformatted the drive to not be encrypted, but in Disk Utility the LaCie drive still shows up as `Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)`

Why is the LaCie drive accessible without password even though it's supposed to be encrypted?
Is there a way to reenable the encryption of the LaCie drive?

As the backup took about 35 hours to complete, I'd prefer to not do it again :/

---

**Edit:** I noticed that when trying to enable TM I couldn't select to use the drive encrypted, and when trying to use it decrypted instead it threw an error *This Core Storage logical volume is already decrypting.*. After some reading [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1288452/error-backing-up-to-encrypted-hfs-backup-disk-using-time-machine-on-high-sierra) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338715/is-it-ok-for-time-machine-to-take-a-long-time-to-decrypt-a-freshly-formatted-enc) I tried running the `diskutil cs list` command, which gave the following result:

```
Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
Encryption Status:       Unlocked
Conversion Status:       Converting (backward)
Reversion State:         Decrypting
----
Conversion Progress:     6%
```

which means that the drive is actually in the process of decrypting. Not exactly sure why or what triggered this (might have misunderstood things earlier and tried to use it as a decrypted TM drive by mistake), but it seems I have to let it run through the decryption process fully before I can encrypt it again. (it's a 4TB drive so guess it'll take days :/ ).

I'll post an update once the drive has been re-encrypted again to see if the original issue still persists.

**Edit 2:** Re-encrypting didn't work and would've taken many times longer than just starting over from scratch, which is what I did instead. Now the drive is encrypted again it's properly asking for pw when plugged in to a new computer.

Comment: Do you use iCloud keychain syncing, or any other password management solution that syncs passwords between machines (1password, lastpass, dashlane, etc.)? Maybe your disk *is* encrypted, but your password manager helped you out.

Comment: That's a good question. I don't use any password syncing between those machines, the second laptop isn't mine, it's a friend's and I've never stored anything on it before.